# customized color map with floating point range for colors in matlab

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I've defined a customized `colormap` and then use it's `colorbar` as you can see in the figure. The min and max of `caxis` is set to be 0 and 16, but the problem is that I want to have floating points in color bar, for example

`[ 0 : 0.3 )=dark blue,  [ 0.3 : 0.6 )=blue, [0.6 : 0.9)=green`
and so on and not just integers, but I can not. please notice  "[" and ")" which are important for me.

please help.

P.S: the gradient effect is not important for me.

here is the code

```
caxis([0 16]);
map = zeros(16 , 3);
map(1:1,:) = [0, 0 ,143]./255;
map(2:2,:) = [0, 0 ,239]./255;
map(3:3,:) = [0, 175 ,255]./255;
map(4:4,:) = [16, 255 ,239]./255;
map(5:5,:) = [112, 255 ,143]./255;
map(6:10,:) = [207, 255 ,48 ; 207, 255 ,48;207, 255 ,48;207, 255 ,48;207, 255 ,48]./255;
map(11:12,:) = [255, 207 ,0 ; 255, 207 ,0 ]./255;
map(13:16,:) = [255, 16 ,0 ; 255, 16 ,0;255, 16 ,0;255, 16 ,0]./255;
colormap(map);
set(get(colorbar('peer',gca),'ylabel'),'String','BGA PC(RFU)');
```

here is the figure :

[image: customized colormap]

Comment: Do you mean to simply change colorbar y-axis labels, or to set the intervals of numbers that get mapped to those colors?

Comment: @LuisMendo: set the intervals of numbers (which contain floating pint numbers) that get mapped to colors,and I think the y-axis label will be changed after that...Please help :(..Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer...the solution is here..I wanted to have a color bar between 0 and 16, with step 0.3  between 0 and 2 and step 0.5 between 2 and 16..sample is here:

> [0 0.3 0.6 0.9...1.8 2.3 2.8...15.8]

so for this I've defined matrix range as shown below:

```
range1 = (0:0.3:2);
range2 = (2.3 : 0.5 : 16); 
range = [range1,range2]';
```

size of matrix range is (35 , 1) so there are 35 points and I should assign 35 colors to these points by defining  `map = zeros(35 ,3 )` . number 3 in map is for  `RGB`. after that I've assigned colors to the map points as below (here is just two of them as an example)

```
map(1,:) = [2, 2 ,51]./255;
map(2,:) = [3, 3 ,88]./255;
```

and here is the complete code for this:

```
contourf(points,depths,FRU01102013);
set(gca, 'XTick', points(1) : points(3), 'XTickLabel',{'LSB1','LSB2-1_BLOOM','LSB2'});
ylabel('Depth(m)');
xlabel('Points');
title('Date: 03.10.2013');
caxis([0 15.8]);
%------------------------
map = zeros(35 , 3);
map(1,:) = [2, 2 ,51]./255;
map(2,:) = [3, 3 ,88]./255;
.
.
.
map(35,:) = [82,3,3]./255;

colormap(map);

%----

range1 = (0:0.3:2);
range2 = (2.3 : 0.5 : 16);
range = [range1,range2]';

cbh = colorbar('peer',gca);
set(cbh,'ytick',range);
set(get(cbh, 'ylabel') ,'String','BGA PC(RFU)');
```

here is the figure:
[image]

I know assigning 35 colors is difficult and maybe stupid but I am not familiar with matlab ...at least it works.